# Can I connect to Neo4j server using Memgraph Lab?

Tags: memgraphdb

I see that Memgraph has [added support for Neo4j](https://github.com/memgraph/gqlalchemy/pull/149) in the OGM and query builder. I know that there is no direct link between GQLAlchemy and Memgraph Lab but I wonder if it possible to connect to Neo4j server using Lab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to connect to Neo4j with Memgraph Lab, but the Lab version needs to be `>= 2.3.0`.